# Searching Firebase Database for two conditions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase structure:

```
"Group" : {
  "34923493" : {
  "Name" : "Group 1"
  "Password" : "whatever1”,
  "Admin" : {
       joeshmoe : true
       janedoe : true
       }
  etc..... 
  }
}
```

What I want do achieve is allow users to join a group; via a view controller that has 2 textboxes:

One that asks for the group id 
and the other that asks for the password

to join that group is the groupid and password pair match that what is in Firebase.

So assuming the uses enters 34923493 as the groupid text box and enters "whatever" as the password in the password text box the lookup would determine that the user matched the two and will be allowed to be added to the group.

I have the following code:

```
ref.child("Group").child(groupID.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

which should only perform the lookup once to join and will not keep any observer on the Group

BUT this doesn't take into consideration that the password is correct in order for the user to join the group?

Has anyone done this already or have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot check in code whether the password value is correct. But it also wouldn't help: if they can read the password, you've already lost your security battle.

As usual with NoSQL databases, you should model the data for the use-case you want to implement. So you could change the data model to this:

```
"Group" : {
  "34923493" : {
    "admin": {
      "Name" : "Group 1"
      etc..... 
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use two `child()` calls to look up the data:

```
ref.child("Group").child(groupID!).child(password!).observeSingleEvent(of:.value...
```

Be sure to secure access to the data:

```
{
  "rules": 
    {
      "Group": {
        "$groupid": {
          "$password": {
            ".read": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

With these rules you can only read the group information if you know its entire path: `/Group/34923493/admin`. You can't simply attach a listener to `/Group` (or even `/Group/34923493`) and steal the information that way.

Comment: I made some edits to clarify what I was asking please read. Also I have a follow-up question when you state the following: "But it also wouldn't help: if they can read the password, you've already lost your security battle." how can they read the password!? if its in the back end in friebase, which nobody should see the data structure??

Comment: The fact that the password is in a back-end database means little if that database is publicly readable or readable by unauthorized users. The security rules snippet I included above shows one way to secure it.

Comment: @ frank so with the edits I made in my init question where you have admin that  would be "whatever"  instead of admin, the reason I ask is because my firebase structure for "Group" does have a json pairing that with admin which lists the users that are admins to the group in question.

Comment: final question, i hope, can the application 'Salt' the password as you can do with SQL DB!? Would that help secure the data?

Comment: Firebase Authentication of course stores its passwords in a secure form. The Firebase Database only supports JSON types, which means there is no "password field" type. Any salting you do to your data will have to happen on the client.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have two follow-up questions. First one is on security; you mentioned if the user knows the entire path (ex. /Groups/34923493/admin). How would the user(s) find out the entire path!? This would not be exposed to anyone but the developers?  Lastly, by changing the json pairing as you outlined (moving the password after id) does that mean now every time i want to retrieve the rest of the data I need to pass along the id and password?

Comment: You'd have to communicate that to them out-of-bounds, similar to how Firebase Authentication send you an email with a password reset code or your bank send you a text message when you transfer money (well... tht's what mine does at least).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so just to be clear, if the password moves to the branch after groupid, to get any info lower in the json tree, the password would have to continually be passed in different views correct?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen by doing it this way, having the group information under the Password under the groupId level, the group owners will never be able to change the password once set?!